# Not able to connect to Vmware ubuntu using Putty in Windows 7

Tags: ssh, vmware

I have installed Vmware Ubuntu in my Windows 7 PC, with network settings as Bridge connection. 
I got IP address in Ubuntu as "192.168.1.3" and I am able to ping that IP from my Windows host, but when I try to connect using the Putty SSH or Telnet connection, it fails.

I have ssh installed in Ubuntu. When my laptop is connected to my office network, the Putty connection works fine, but when I'm connected to my home network, it fails.

Is there any settings I'm missing?

Comment: I am not clear on the parts and components of this question. Are there three machines: Windows Host, Ubuntu VMWare guest, and some other server or is this just connectivity between your Windows host and your VMware Ubuntu guest?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot for the failed msg ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue with me. 
Sometime your incompatible network adapter is the issue for connection failure.

If you are using WIFI - NAT/Bridge works better but if you are connected using Ethernet - Use only Bridge Adapter.

Vmware automatically defines network adapter configuration based on network adapter selection. To setup it manually-

- Open VMware
- File Menu --> Edit
- Virtual Network Editor
- Change setting
- Add Network --> VMnet10 --> OK
- Under VMnet information --> Bridged
- Select Bridged to --> Automatic --> OK
- Go to your VM and select the Network Adapter --> Bridge connection.

Hope this helps.
Thanks